# Best method for multi-page user registration form?

Tags: 7, webforms, users

I am trying to set up a multi-page user registration form, and I would ideally like to use the Webform module to do so. Can webform fields be mapped to user registration or user profile fields?

Here's how I would like it to work:

1. User tries to access content page; they cannot because they are not registered, so they are prompted to create a new account.
2. They enter their name, email, password and are logged in. They are then redirected to "page 1" of the multi-page form.
3. After they go through all of the pages, they save the form. The info they entered into the pages of the form is saved in their user profile. They can go back in and edit it at a later date if they wish.

Is this possible with existing modules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) and [Profile2 Registration Path](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) modules can help to solve your problems. You can do the following:

- You can create the profile for each role of users.
- Have the different register pages for each profiles.
- Can config the way to do after registration.
- Have the edit user information with include the extra fields from Profile2 module.